# Outlook: Is it possible to warn me before I'm sending an email to the number of recipients?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

Is there a way to prevent me from sending out emails to greater than a certain number of people?  I don't want to accidentally reply all or send to a wrong distribution list.  I was wondering if it would be possible to have outlook prompt me if the email I'm about to send is going to more than, let's say 5 people.  Does this even make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Outlook client, but in any case, beware of mailing lists: It seems pretty much impossible to discern a mailing list from a "normal" recipient (without maintaining a list of *all* possible mailing lists in your environment).

If that's not a problem for you, it might be possible to write a (VBA?) macro that hooks is invoked when pressing the "send" button, asking you for confirmation if the number of recepients is greater than some predefined value.

[This](http://lifehacker.com/5259507/use-an-outlook-macro-to-stop-forgetting-the-subject-line) describes how to implement something very similar (it asks for confirmation before sending when the subject line is empty); you should probably be able to modify it accordingly.